# CSRF problem: Django-registration app with my custom login-form in my base.html

Tags: django, csrf, django-registration

Im using https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/ for login and registration in Django.

But now im trying to add an login-form in my base.html, with a simple form
{% csrf_token %}... etc

The thing is when i login it says CSRF verification fails, i guess this is because the data isnt sent from templates/registration/login.html ?

Any idea how I should solve this in an easy way, will I have to write my own login-view?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what happens before it fails?  Are you accessing the URL from somewhere else (e.g. a registration email)?

Comment: Didnt send the csrf info with the view.. it isnt easy when you'r new :)

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the page of "http://***/accounts/register/" that contains your form not Forbidden after you add {% csrf_token %}.